# Git Pull Request - Csproj - Duplicate package reference entries

Tags: git, pull-request, csproj

I am getting into a weird situation, every time I do a nuget package update for a specific package and then create a pull request for it.

The update of the package works fine, no problem there, but when I do the pull request, the package reference in the .csproj file gets duplicated, as in:

`<PackageReference Include="[package_name]" Version="[old_version]" />`

`<PackageReference Include="[package_name]" Version="[new_version]" />`

Did anyone encounter this issue? What would the reason and the solution? Thanks.

Comment: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command, `git merge` by default*. The `git merge` command means *combine their changes and my changes*. The combining is done by Git on a purely line-by-line textual basis. The csproj file contains XML, which cannot be correctly merged on a line-by-line textual basis. The result is an invalid XML file. Do not let Git merge this file. How you go about the "not let Git merge this file" part is up to you.